# karate : .intuit.karate.http.DummyHttpClient - attempt to build url: http://localhost:8089/, but dummy http client in use

Tags: karate

I am getting below error and url is not getting set for Karate 
12:04:39.896 [main] WARN  c.intuit.karate.http.DummyHttpClient - attempt to build url: http://localhost:8089/, but dummy http client in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you tried to directly use the `karate-core` maven dependency without reading the documentation. Please follow the quickstart instructions:

https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.intuit.karate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=karate-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=0.9.0 \
-DgroupId=com.mycompany \
-DartifactId=myproject
```